# How to hide an element automatically after completion of recording in kamiazya/ngx-speech-recognition angular version

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a text box and a listen button,When you click listen it will start recording and appending to the textbox and 'Listening..' text will be visible. Now my requirement is when I click 'stop listening' button in between anytime recording should be stop and also 'listening..' text should be hide. Also suppose my recording ends before click 'stop listening..' button, 'listening'..' text should be hide after finish recording automatically. Here is the demo I have created https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wyphh6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. Also please find the code below.

### app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>

<p><input type="text" value="{{message}}"></p>
  <button

    (click)="listen()"
  >listen</button>
<p [hidden]="listening">Listening..</p>
<button [hidden]="listening">Stop Listening</button>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RxSpeechRecognitionService, resultList, } from '@kamiazya/ngx-speech-recognition';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  providers: [ RxSpeechRecognitionService ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  message = '';
  listening:boolean = true;
constructor(public service: RxSpeechRecognitionService) {


         }

     listen() {
       this.listening = false;
    this.service
      .listen()
      .pipe(resultList)
      .subscribe((list: SpeechRecognitionResultList) => {
        this.message = list.item(0).item(0).transcript;
        console.log('RxComponent:onresult', this.message, list);

      });

  }
  }
```

Comment: You should add `@kamiazya/ngx-speech-recognition` as a package dependency in your stackblitz project

Comment: also it has dependency to @angular/cdk. and also worth to mention that it only works on chrome.

Comment: I have already added the package,Its working fine but my requirement is when I click 'stop listening' button in between anytime recording should be stop and also 'listening..' text should be hide. Also suppose my recording ends before click 'stop listening..' button, 'listening'..' text should be hide after finish recording automatically

Answer (score 0):

I have forked your [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p6i7bf). For stopping listening add `takeUntil` [operator] (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html) to the pipe. Used a boolean [subject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/subject.html) to destroy subscription. So your app.component ts become like this:

```
  ....
  stop = new Subject<boolean>();      
  listen() {
    this.listening = true;
    this.service
      .listen()
      .pipe(
        resultList,
        takeUntil(this.stop)
      )
      .subscribe((list: SpeechRecognitionResultList) => {
        const item = list.item(0);
        this.message = item.item(0).transcript;
        console.log("RxComponent:onresult", this.message, list);
        if (item.isFinal) { // this is set true when stream ends
          this.listening = false; // so its good time to set false
        }
      });
  }

  stopListening() {
    this.listening = false;
    this.stop.next(true);
  }
```

And in your view used *ngIfs to hide and show necessary parts of your view :

```
  <button  
    (click)="listen()"
  >listen</button>
<p *ngIf="listening">Listening..</p>
<button *ngIf="listening" (click)="stopListening()">Stop Listening</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.here one small issue is there once I click ''Stop Listening" button and again click  "Listen" button, recording is not happening.

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER it seems when you unsubscribe from the observable than `listen()` method provides, it causes errors and makes it impossible to subscribe to it again.

Comment: So what is the solution for it